# Button classes that I've written with C# won't show up in Windows Form when running

Tags: c#, winforms, button, methods

Just started learning Visual Studio and I'm trying to make a soundboard in Windows Forms.
ButtonMaker(); is the function I use to make a button for each soundfile in my directory so I don't have to make 70 different buttons for every sound, but when I run the program nothing shows up in the forms window. Anybody know why? I've tried calling the function in Main() and in the initial Form1 class but nothing happens in either. Forms class file here:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MySoundBoard
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ///Tried running it here

            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///Tried running it here
        }


        private void ButtonMaker()
        {
            string[] files = Soundfiles.GetFile();
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                string btnName = item.ToUpper();
                Button btNname = new Button();
                btNname.Text = item;
                int x = 40;
                int y = 40;
                btNname.Location = new Point(x, y);
                x = x + 50;
                if (x>900)
                {
                    x = 40;
                    y = y + 30;
                }
                

            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the SoundFiles class:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WMPLib;


namespace MySoundBoard
{
    class Soundfiles    {

        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer Player;


        static public string[] GetFile() {
            string txtPath = @"C:\Documents\path\to\sound effects";

            string[] files =
            Directory.GetFiles(txtPath, "*ProfileHandler.cs", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                
            return files;
        }
        public void PlayFile(String url)
        {
            Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
            Player.URL = url;
            Player.controls.play();
        }


    }

    
}
```

And the main project file(not that worked with yet):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MySoundBoard
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            ///Tried running it here
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

        }
    }
}
```

As said, I'm very new to this language and any help would be appriciated!

Comment: You are creating buttons, but not adding them to an element like a Panel .

Comment: You are missing an instruction :  this.Controls.Add(btNname);

Comment: `int x = 40; int y = 40;` should be outside the loop, otherwise... You should probably find means other than Buttons to present your files. A ListView, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You create the buttons but never add them to the form. Just add

```
this.Controls.Add(btNname);
```

The next thing is, that your buttons will not do something. You'll need to add an event handler as well.

```
btNname.Click += ...;
```

In order to know which button plays which sound, you need to find a way to have that association. A hacky approach is

```
btNname.Tag = item;
```

and then evaluate `Tag` later

Comment: This helped a lot! Thanks!